# Symfony - Infinite loop when handling circular references

Tags: json, symfony, circular-reference

I'm currently trying to serialize an array that has circular references. To handle the circular references, I took the code from Symfony Docs

```
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(2);
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
    return $object->getId();
});
$normalizers = array($normalizer);
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$json = $serializer->serialize($myArray, 'json');
```

However, when I try to run the code, the page keeps on loading infinitely, no exception is thrown, no log are generated, and the only way to recover is to kill the server and re-run it.

I cannot `var_dump` the variable `$myArray` because it is self-referencing, thus making the instruction looping indefinitely.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Commande {#2155 ▼
    #commerce: Commerce {#2623 ▶}
    #stripe_charge: null
    #id: 2
    #user: "admin"
    #commerce_nom: null
    #valide: false
    #cloture: false
    #paye: false
    #livre: false
    #date_livraison: null
    #livraison_remarque: null
    #valide_remarque: null
    #cout: CommandeCout {#2812 ▶}
    #lieu_livraison: null
    #commande_produits: PersistentCollection {#2671 ▶}
    #createdAt: DateTime @1520264795 {#2056 ▶}
    #updatedAt: DateTime @1520264795 {#2055 ▶}
  }
  1 => Commande {#2791 ▼
    #commerce: Commerce {#2788 ▶}
    #stripe_charge: null
    #id: 3
    #user: "admin"
    #commerce_nom: null
    #valide: false
    #cloture: false
    #paye: false
    #livre: false
    #date_livraison: null
    #livraison_remarque: null
    #valide_remarque: null
    #cout: CommandeCout {#2811 ▶}
    #lieu_livraison: null
    #commande_produits: PersistentCollection {#2780 ▶}
    #createdAt: DateTime @1520339269 {#2797 ▶}
    #updatedAt: DateTime @1520339269 {#2796 ▶}
  }
]
```

The field "commande_produits" contains references to the object "Commande#2155". I don't understand why the circular handler I used won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in that case it would be best to instruct Doctrine to do extra lazy loading in the reference declaration in your entities, as shown in the example below :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Commande", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
public $commande_produits;
```